# County Finder form/plugin?

Tags: plugins, filters, forms

I'm developing a WP site for a client and need to build in a "county finder" for our state (VT).  Users would type the name of a town into a field  (or select the town from a drop-down menu), press the submit button, and the system would spit out the name of the county that the town is located in.  Ideally the results are delivered within the page, no new page load required, but that's not essential.

I'm not expecting to find a pre-made solution...I'll have to enter the towns and counties manually of course...but I wasn't even sure what to look for in this case.

Any suggestions appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Dadra,

A bit off the WordPress topic, but you may want to consider using the US Census API to do your lookups.

Integrating this into WP should be pretty simple, could be done by zipcode, city name, etc... and could be done with and AJAX callback all on one page.

Example of what I think you want: http://quickfacts.census.gov/cgi-bin/qfd/lookup
US Census API Developer site: http://www.census.gov/developers/

For specific WP implementation methods, I'm thinking you may want to hire someone with a fairly solid background with external API integrations.